# Is it possible to increase the value of a variable by the value of a state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a global variable which I'm trying to increase by the value of items from an array within a state.

```
total = 0;
for (let item of this.state.values) {
    this.total= this.total + item.value;
}
```

At the moment the values are being added to the number behind the original, for instance if item.value gives me a 3 first then a 5, I will get total = 035, not total = 8 which is what I want.

I originally forgot to mention that the numbers within the array are strings which I got from an api.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are they strings rather than numbers?

Comment: they are strings, my apologies I forgot to mention that

Comment: well that is why then. strings concat together, numbers add. so convert to numbers and it should work

Comment: "2"+"5" = "25" 2 + 5 = 7

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I converted the value to a number and it works, sorry for the beginner level question

Comment: no worries! have a good day